# Git Branch only pulls Master Branch in GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I am working with GitHub actions and I am trying to get the last branch that was merged into master and use that branch. I am currently trying to use.

```
echo "::set-output name=branch::$(git branch --merged master | tail -1)"
```

I am using this in the action.yml. I am only getting master from this rather than the other branches that I merged in. Does anyone understand why this might be. I even ran a fetch before hand to make sure the right information was on the local machine. My assumption is that it is not getting closed branches once they are merged. Is this possible in any way?

Cheers,

Comment: You probably had GitHub make a single-branch clone. In any case you would want `git branch -r --merged master` for any normal clone, since cloning doesn't copy the branch names (it renames them to become remote-tracking names instead).

Comment: Hey @torek thanks for the insight I tried adding the -r flag which added origin/master to the list but didn't pull in any of the other branches that were merged and closed. You mention single branch clone. Is there a way for the clone to take all of the branches?

Comment: Yes: set the depth to 0 with the "checkout@v2" action, or use the older (v1) checkout action.

Comment: @torek I have attempted this int he Github action and it keeps pulling origin/master even when I use the depth of "0" in checkout@v2.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "pulling" here. The Git command `git pull` is something that is run by *humans:* it means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*. It should never be used in any automation because it's too difficult to control the two commands. Instead, automated software should run each command individually. This gives you much more control. (You then need to post the actual commands you're running.)

Answer (score 0):

The part I was missing was the ordering which is wrong because master pulls itself in and considers itself committed last. I fixed this by using.

```
git branch --sort=committerdate -rav --merged master | tail -2 | head -1
```

This gets the right order and the second item from the list.